# Slick slider not append custom arrows to DOM in production version of site, but all ok in source

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, slider, slick.js

In the source version site slick slider work and arrows there is DOM.

http://spotlight.devbucket.me/www/index.html

But in production site slick slider is init, it's seen in chrome inspector. No arrows in DOM, not work slider.

http://spotlight.devbucket.me/

All files the same in all versions.

I'm confused - where is the mistake?
Please help me, and sorry for my English.

Comment: How did you initialize them both? Could you post the snippets?

Comment: You don't see arrows in production because there are not enough items. If you reduce the width of the window you will see them.

Comment: @Manolo Santos Ah , yes, indeed. Thank you very much! I'm the fool here) Sometimes what you think about a problem as big and simple solution , you can not see )